# Object required when using GetList function for concatenation

Tags: vba, ms-access

**OBJECTIVE**: To concatenate row values

```
Record in COMP table
    player_id        cc_number
    1                123
    2                152
    1                254
    2                154
    3                256

Result to be
    player_id        cc_number
    1                123, 254
    2                152, 154
    3                256
```

**CODE**:

```
MYSQL = "Select T.player_id, "
MYSQL = MYSQL & GetList("Select cc_number From COMP As T1 Where T1.player_id = " & [T].[player_id], "", ", ") & " AS NewCCNumber"
MYSQL = MYSQL & "From COMP AS T"
MYSQL = MYSQL & "Group By T.player_id"
```

**ERROR**:
i used GetList function but it gives me error Object Required.

Comment: What do you plan to do with this SQL statement - open a recordset?

Answer (score 1):

Need space in front of FROM and GROUP or after NewCCNumber and T. Otherwise text strings run together. Also, the GetList() function should probably be embedded in string

```
MYSQL = "Select T.player_id, "
MYSQL = MYSQL & "GetList('Select cc_number From COMP As T1 Where T1.player_id = " & [T].[player_id] & "', '', ', ') As NewCCNumber "
MYSQL = MYSQL & "From COMP As T "
MYSQL = MYSQL & "Group By T.player_id"
```